# is charset=utf-8 need it in js and css files even if my html has <meta charset="UTF-8">

Tags: character-encoding, mime-types

is it already implied that without a charset, the charset of the text/plain, application/javascript and text/css MIME types should be interpreted as the same as that the HTML caller? 
if needed, what other MIME types need to add charset? application/json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need and should not declare charset for JavaScript files if it has the same encoding declared in your HTML file. Same goes for CSS files, as you can see [on W3C page](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en.html). JSON shall even be encoded in UTF-8/UTF-16/UTF-32 and its default is UTF-8 as [IETF states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-8.1) . So you should not add a charset attribute to that.

Also some MIME type should not have charset parameters at all. JSON is one of them.
So you see it can vary which MIME type can have a charset parameters and which don't even have that parameter at all.

As stated above, it mostly is enough to have your CSS/JavaScript etc. files the same encoding as HTML as it it mostly UTF-8. Additionally your Server itself should define and tell the browser what charset is used.